# Rails - set comma as default delimiter for float

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some attributes of float type and here in Brazil, the delimiter for decimals is comma, and dot as milliar delimiter. So, for example, "3,004.65" would be "3.000,05". I don't wanna change every input and format every output to that format, 'cause it would be not really DRY. Is there some easy way to do that on a initializer, for example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like https://github.com/clemens/delocalize might be an option. The gem lets you set something like:

```
  number:
    format:
      separator: ','
      delimiter: '.'
```

in a yaml file. Thats interesting though I didn't know so many countries inverted this format!

Comment: change the locale doesn't help me so much... my biggest problem is on forms. I have to format the value before save on database, and for editing I have to format it back. Keep doing these conversions every time seems a bad way to do it

Comment: took a better look at it, and think it's gonna help. But it sucks that rails doesn't permit to config that globally yet...